# Couchbase stuck at re-balancing 0 nodes

Tags: couchbase

I have a Couchbase cluster of 3 nodes. 2 of them went down briefly and came back up, after which I started re-balancing from couchbase console.

However, the console is showing `Rebalancing 0 nodes` for past 28 hours. I tried to stop the rebalance but it's stuck with the same message.

When I used command line tool to stop the rebalance I get the following message:

```
$ /opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-cli rebalance-stop -c 127.0.0.1:8091 -u my-admin -p my-password
$ SUCCESS: rebalance cluster stopped
```

Yet, it's not actually stopped and the popover in console is still there. Is there any way I can fix it? I have already tried restarting both servers (that are stuck in pending).

**EDIT:**

I ended up pushing data on a different cluster using XDCR and then shutting down the entire cluster (even restarting all nodes didn't work). Some data was lost.

I'm keeping this open in case anyone has a better solution for such situation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a known issue with Couchbase since at least version 2.5.1 through version 4.0.0:

https://forums.couchbase.com/t/rebalance-stuck-at-0-and-does-not-cancel/6568

Looks like you need to know how their erlang setup works and how to restart ns_server from there.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to remove the node from the cluster and then re-add it to the cluster?

Comment: It won't let me remove any node.